# How to move opencart site http to https

Tags: ssl, https, opencart

I have already installed ssl certificate on my opencart site but some pages are working fine with https but category pages not working with https. Do I need to change all url in database also? In the config file, I already set https.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of these may not apply to your particular installation but in the interest of creating a comprehensive answer, I've tried to cover all the bases here:

*Note: you might need to adjust the table names depending on your store's table prefix if they don't begin with `oc_`*

- Open `config.php` and `admin/config.php` and change all those constant url declarations to https - make sure to include `HTTP_SERVER` and `HTTP_CATALOG`
- In your admin panel go to `system > settings`, click `edit` and in the `server` table set `Use SSL:` to `Yes`.
- In your database update the `store_url` column in the `oc_order` table so that all links are https.  This is important because updating orders can fail if the api attempts to access http version of your site.  you can use this query: `UPDATE oc_order SET store_url = REPLACE(store_url, 'http:', 'https:')`
- If you have any hard coded images and links in your description tables you should replace those as well.  SSL will still work but will show the warning flag in the browser bar.  This includes `oc_product_description`, `oc_category_description`, and any other tables where you might have created html content.
- Same as above for your theme files. It's fairly common to find hard coded `http://` links and images in `footer.tpl` and `header.tpl` for starters.  You can simply browser your site to see if any of the pages are not showing the green lock icon in the browser and take it from there.
- Another culprit breaking https can be third party extensions which can exist both as files and in OC2 as ocmods in the `oc_modification` table.
- Finally, create a redirect in `.httaccess` to gracefully let traffic know that your pages can now be found on https. I've excluded `robots.txt` and any connections for the openbay routes because, based on experience, when I tried to redirect ebay webhooks it broke things and they seem to be `http` only by default.  I suspect this may be a shortcoming in how openbay handles those requests, or possibly a configuration issue but I was unable to find a workaround that didn't break openbay so for now I'd recommend leaving those requests untouched. I am using this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^route=ebay/openbay/*
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

That should do it!